# Assigning Array To Property That Has A List Of Items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, properties, assign

I have some pre-existing JavasSript code that looks like the following:

```
function createContexMenu() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-target',
        callback: function (key, options) {},
        items: {
            "cut"   : { name: "Cut", icon: "cut.png"},
            "copy"  : { name: "Copy", icon: "copy.png"},
            "paste" : { name: "Paste", icon: "paste.png"},
        }                
        };
    });
}
```

As you can see, three properties are being set: selector, callback, and items.

I need to modify this code so that the items property is not hard-coded as it is now. I need to pass in an array of items into the function createContextMenu.

So the simple change to the function is to add a parameter, I called it menuItems:

```
function createContexMenu(menuItems) {
```

In the code prior to calling createContextMenu I need to setup the array of menu items and then pass them to createContextMenu through the newly added parameter.

Here is how I think I should do it:

```
var cut, copy, paste, items;
cut = { name: "Cut", icon: "cut.png" };
copy = { name: "Copy", icon: "copy.png" };
paste = { name: "Paste", icon: "paste.png" };
items = [ cut, copy, paste ];
createContexMenu(items);
```

Assuming I setup the array correctly lets now move on the the more difficult issue. Taking the items from the array and assigning them to the items property in the createContextMenuFunction.

Do I do something like iterate through all the items and add each one? Something like this:

```
selector: '.context-menu-target',
callback: function (key, options) {},
for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i += 1) {
    menuItem = menuItems[i];
    items: {
        menuItem.name : { name: menuItem.name, icon : menuItem.icon };
    }
}
```

Or can I somehow just assign items to the array like this:

```
items = menuItems;
```

or

```
items : {
    menuItems;
}
```

?

Thank you.

~J

Comment: I'm not sure, but this include `jQuery` code, if so add a jquery tag also.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am not sure what you mean? I am new to all this javascript, jquery stuff and it's probably obvious. :)

Comment: no I was just saying that if you are using `jquery` in your code, better to add that as tag in your question.

Comment: you first way is pretty good & straightforward, and your second & third   way won't give the expected output, so better go with your first way. Because `Objects` assign there reference your first way removes that problem also.

Comment: When you say first way do you mean hard-coding the values? That's exactly what I am trying to move away from.

Comment: I think doing just `items: menuItems` should just work fine. But you need to declare `items` as `items = { 'cut': cut, ...}` outside your function

Comment: no I mean `iterating` over array, anyway you have to iterate, because you are passing an `array` & you want an object.